# Basic questions on openejb with TOMEE

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, cdi, apache-tomee, openejb

I am a newbee to openEJB and would want to understand a few things about it to overcome a problem I face when deploying one application onto TOMEE.

From what I understand, openEJB is a lightweight container to host and run EJB components. Which inturn means, things would work through JNDI lookups. Is this right?

I have the below scenario now:

1. I have a camel context initialized through spring , packaged as war and deployed on tomee
2. I recently included a third party dependency which enabled CDI capabilities causing openEJB to be used. why is this so?
3. My WAR deployment used to work on tomee before introducing the third party dependency but after introducing the dependency there are CXF component related errors (irrespective of what is used under exclusions.list like described in a similar issue http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Camel-CXF-in-tomee-td4681184.html )

Below are more questions:

1. Is there an option to use openEJB only for the third party JAR and not for the whole camel application?
2. how is the architecture of the TOMEE container when openejb is used? will spring container be inside the openEJB container? does the lookup for spring components also start using JNDI lookups or just the normal spring lookups?

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is good practice in Stackoverflow to ask one question per question... And tomee already is java-ee, so there would be no need for open-ejb if that third-party app is developed correctly (against api's, not implementations), so it might be that you added the dependency in a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Does tomee use openejb internally? Because I see openejb jars inside of the lib directory.  If I do not want openejb to be used,  what's the best way I could tell Tomee to not use openejb and instead bring the application up just using java-ee capabilities of tomee.

Comment: No Idea, don't use it myself. Google is your Friends. Regarding the 'telling not to uses is totally dependent oh how you package things...

Comment: i think the TomEE project originally started as OpenEJB.  the EJB means Enterprise Java Beans and OpenEJB is the bit that brings in all the JavaEE stuff.  TomEE is basically Tomcat packaged with OpenEJB and (loads of) other stuff.